# Team building algorithm based on rank order preferences

Tags: optimization

I have a dataset with employees at four levels of training: junior employee, senior employee, junior manager, senior manager. I am looking to match them into teams of 4, each team with 1 person from each level.

Each person has ranked four attributes into preferences 1-4, with 1 being their top preference and 4 being their bottom preference. A sample of the data looks like this:

```
Employee Type   | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | Attribute 3 | Attribute 4
Junior Employee |      2      |      3      |      1      |      4      
Junior Manager  |      1      |      2      |      4      |      3      
Senior Employee |      4      |      3      |      2      |      1      
Junior Manager  |      3      |      1      |      2      |      4      
Senior Manager  |      2      |      4      |      1      |      3      
Junior Employee |      2      |      3      |      4      |      1      
... (n=300)
```

The goal would be to have teams that look like:

```
Team 1: [Junior Employee #3, Senior Employee #5, Junior Manager #1, Senior Manager #4]
Team 3: [Junior Employee #2, Senior Employee #1, Junior Manager #2, Senior Manager #3]
```

And so on...

I would appreciate any help as to the most efficient matching algorithm to use here. My initial thought was to use a variation of the Gale–Shapley algorithm, though I can't quite figure out how to apply it to attribute preferences rather than people preferences. Thanks!